# Given a location's coordinate, locally find out the zip-code without any Web API

Tags: gis, postgis, reverse-geocoding, shapefile

I'm working on the visualization of a large spatial data set(around 2.5 million records) using Google maps on a web site. The data points correspond to geographic coordinates within a City. I'm trying to group the data points based on their zip codes so that I can visualize some form of statistical information for each of the zip codes within the city.

The Google API provides an option for "reverse-geocoding" a point to get the zipcode but it enforces a usage limit of 2500 per IP per day. Given the size of my data set I don't think Google or any other limit enforced Web API is practical.

Now, after a few rounds of Google search I've found out that it is possible to set up a spatial database if we have the boundary data for the zip codes. I've downloaded the said boundary data but they're in what is known as "shapefile" format. I'm trying to use PostGIS to set up a spatial database that I can query on for each data point to find out which zipcode it belongs to.

Am I headed in the right direction?

If yes, can someone please share any known examples that have done something similar as I seem to have reached a dead end with PostGIS.

If no, can you please point me to the right course of action given my requirements.

Thanks.

Comment: You need 1) a database of GIS coordinates and corresponding .zip codes, and 2) an algorithm to look up the zip code for a coordinate (or vice versa).  Google Maps provides both.  [GEOTools](http://geotools.org/) might be another option.

Comment: @paulsm4 Thanks. But as I've mentioned above Google API is not feasible for me as the no of queries is huge. Is it possible to set up the two locally?

Comment: You need to import shapefile into post gis, [http://workshops.opengeo.org/postgis-intro/loading_data.html](http://workshops.opengeo.org/postgis-intro/loading_data.html) first.   Then perform query picking a polygon that contains the point of interest, [http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ST_Contains.html](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ST_Contains.html) .  Make sure that shape files' projection is in WGS84 as your "geographic coordinate" is most likely defined on that coordinate.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to point to this page "ST_Contains" at http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ST_Contains.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply @yosukesabai. It seems that the "map datum" used in the shapefiles is in NAD83 format, which it seems is same as WGS84. 
I've loaded the shapefiles to PostGIS as you suggested and am now trying to query on each polygon. 
One related question: I've heard that there are algorithms similar to KNearestNeighbor that can be used to select the closest point to a given coordinate. Would it help to do this first to identify the closest zip-codes and then use the ST_contain function to verify the selection?
Thanks.

Comment: Most of GIS implementation has worked that problem outs.  For PostGIS, it seems like Spatial Indexing http://workshops.opengeo.org/postgis-intro/indexing.html .  SO make sure that you do appropriate action to take advantage of that feature.